# Insert the attribute value of input element in form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form with no `id` or `class`. I need to insert attribute values for  input elements.

```
<form>
    <tr><td><input type="text" name="x"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="text" name="y"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="text" name="z"/></td></tr>
</form>
```

Here's jquery I tried:

```
var x = $('form').find('input').first().val("some_value");
var y = $('form').find('input').second().val("some_value");
var z = $('form').find('input').third().val("some_value");
```

// Is there another possible way?

```
var x  = $("form").find('input[name="x"]').val("some_value");
```

Comment: There is no `second` or `third` methods in jQuery

Comment: why cant you add a id for the element and access it..

Comment: Is there a problem you're having, or do you just want 'other ways' of achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Attribute Equals Selector [name=”value”]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to uniquely identify the inputs

```
$('input[name=x]').val("some_value1");
$('input[name=y]').val("some_value2");
$('input[name=z]').val("some_value3");
```

Although I wont recommend the method you used to assign values to input, I would suggest you to use `find()` once and use the returned object collection to assign values. This will reduce the processing time and increase performance.

```
var all = $('form').find('input');
all.eq(0).val("some_value1");
all.eq(1).val("some_value2");
all.eq(2).val("some_value3");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$("form").find('input[type="text"]]').each(function() {
    $(this).attr("your attribute", "your value");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try with this

```js
var x  = $('form input[name="x"]').val("some_value_x");
```

Answer (score 1):

// So you can search across the form for all input elements and then iterate to apply the attribute.

```js
 var allInputElements = $("form input[type='text']");
   $.each(allInputElements,function(index, item){
       $(item).attr("disabled","true");      
      // You can also use item.prop("any property or attribute","value");
   });
```

Comment: You don't need to use `.each()` -- `.attr()` can be used on a collection and it will update them all.

Answer (score 1):

If you're giving them all the same value, as it appears in your question, you can simply select them all:

```
$("form input").val("some_value");
```